# set data for navigation in highstock

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am working with highstock (highchart). I need to set data for navigation bar from a seperate array.

my json format is :

```
[{"SensorID":2,"Temperature":34.0,"Humidity":56.0,"Carbon":87.0,"DateTime":"2017-03-08T10:07:00","ID":10},{"SensorID":2,"Temperature":34.0,"Humidity":43.0,"Carbon":87.0,"DateTime":"2017-03-09T12:00:00","ID":12},{"SensorID":2,"Temperature":23.0,"Humidity":89.0,"Carbon":65.0,"DateTime":"2017-03-09T12:00:00","ID":13},{"SensorID":2,"Temperature":34.0,"Humidity":56.0,"Carbon":87.0,"DateTime":"2017-03-08T10:07:00","ID":16},{"SensorID":2,"Temperature":87.0,"Humidity":34.0,"Carbon":23.0,"DateTime":"2017-03-08T10:07:00","ID":18},{"SensorID":2,"Temperature":44.0,"Humidity":67.0,"Carbon":43.0,"DateTime":"2017-03-08T10:07:00","ID":20},{"SensorID":2,"Temperature":100.0,"Humidity":100.0,"Carbon":100.0,"DateTime":"2017-03-08T10:07:00","ID":21},{"SensorID":2,"Temperature":70.0,"Humidity":20.0,"Carbon":50.0,"DateTime":"2017-03-08T10:07:00","ID":22}]
```

I am pushing this data into different arrays like humidity_array, Date_array etc and assigning these array to series of chart. But how can I assign date_array to navigation bar in highstock dynamically .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add it or update as normal series but with [showInNavigator](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock/plotOptions.area.showInNavigator) set to `true` and [visible](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock/Series.visible) to false.

```
  chart.addSeries({
    data: [4,3,2,1],
    showInNavigator: true,
    visible: false
  });
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/q8xe7qLp/